# How do I get javascript to return this value?

Tags: javascript

The alert works, but the return is 0.  How do I get it to return the correct value?

```
var img;
img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
   alert(img.width);
   return(img.width);
};
img.src = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/dir/bike.png";
alert(img.width);
```

Comment: `onload` will be executed at an arbitrary point in the future: do what you need to do in the onload function itself.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you are actually trying to accomplish. Then somebody might be able to give you a way to get there.

Comment: Where are you trying to return `img.width` to? The more information you give, the better you can be helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that.  `onload` runs once the image is loaded, which means after setting the `src`, `onload` will run later.

You need to put all code dealing with the image's width inside the `onload`.

Answer (score 2):

You can return the value, but you have no way of capturing it.

The function you pass to `onload` is executed, when your image has loaded. But there is no way to retrieve the return value there. You can just call another function inside, to process the value.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to return that value?

Comment: @user1357182 Just by calling another function and passing it on as a parameter. That's the nature of asynchronous coding.

Answer (score 0):

I get `10` from this code in Chrome:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { console.log(img.width); }
img.src = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/dir/bike.png";
```

You do have to wait for the image to load before querying width (in `onload`).